# Should tags Precision and Accuracy be merged?

Tags: discussion, tagging

I understand that conceptually *precision* and *accuracy* are quite distinct, but pragmatically tags [precision](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/precision) and [accuracy](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/accuracy) appear to be redundant:

> *precision*
>
> Questions dealing with the relative uncertainty in the values computed, stored, or manipulated by Mathematica.
>
> *accuracy*
>
> Questions about numerical accuracy, precision, artifacts, rounding errors, ways to control them and circumvent the issues.

Should both tags be preserved or should one be made a synonym of the other?

(There are also tags [machine-precision](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/machine-precision) and [arbitrary-precision](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arbitrary-precision) which appear well differentiated.)

Comment: I'd say make them synonyms, one of the other or both of tag [tag:precision-and-accuracy].

Comment: The questioner is likely to be confused about the difference between the two.

Comment: @MichaelE2 +1 and  Must-be-in-the-wiki post: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/118249/5478

Comment: @MichaelE2 I have made both tags synonyms of [accuracy-and-precision](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/accuracy-and-precision).  I will hold off merging in case there are unforeseen problems.

Comment: Tiny nitpick: the docs typically use the phrasing "precision and accuracy" not "accuracy and precision". Also, "precision" is the more natural concept (*in Mathematica!*), so it may be good to have it be the primary thing.  Finally, "accuracy-and-precision" is visually similar to "arbitrary-precision" and can potentially be confused when skimming tags before the morning coffee.  Yes, it's a very nitty nitpick (is that a word?) :-)

Comment: @Szabolcs Thanks for your feedback.  I think you make a good argument.  Incidentally I made a Google search for both "accuracy and precision" and "precision and accuracy" and found that the former was more common and went with that.